# DebugView Error

Tags: debugview

I'm working with Windows 7 64X and DebugView 4.76.0.0.

Logs isn't shown on DebugView.
I trying to write logs with Debug.WriteLine("Text"); and see nothing.
I can see that It's connected to my computer.

When I use DebugView V4.64.0.0 I get error message that it is already connected to other instance of DebugView, but I've checked and there isn't any other.

What can I do or check ?

BTW,
I can see the log in the output window.

Regards,
Eitan Gabay

Answer (score 3):

To check if you really have another instance of debugview running, open up your task manager, and select "show processes from all users".  Make sure that only one debugview is running.

When debugging through Visual Studio, Visual Studio actually **competes** against DebugView.  If you were to compile your executable, and run it externally, you will see your log messages printed in DebugView.

One other thing that people sometimes overlook is that Debug.Write statements are excluded if a program is compiled for Release.  However, you can still write to the trace if you use Trace.Write instead of Debug.Write.

All messages that you print go to a shared section of memory called DB_WINBUFFER [link](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/outputdebugstring.html). It is important to realize that each windows session has its own "DB_WINBUFFER".  Whenever DebugView detects that you are **not** in session 0, it will provide a "Capture Global" option.  If your program is running as a windows service, then you will need to enable capture global (unless you are already in Session 0, which is only possible in Windows XP).